What's the appropriate asking price for domain that another company asks me to sell to them?
I own a dot.com domain (which differs by one letter from my company's main domain name). I have owned this domain for more than 15 years. A new company whose name matches the domain name has just asked me to sell the domain to them. It's a newly registered company in UK whose business is video production, IT consultancy, and computer repair. What's the appropriate asking price?
I've never sold any domains before. Various AI tools suggested asking price from $1000 to $15000. I hope that experienced members here can give appropriate advice.
Thanks!

It's going to depend entirely on what the domain is.  How many letters, whether it's an actual word etc.  I think you'll need to give the domain, or an example of a very similar one, for people to advise.

@RichardB it's basically their company name, 6 letters, as in namexx.com; not an actual word, made up name.

The best way to price your domain is to try to figure out as accurately as you can how much the seller would be willing to pay. Conversely, they will likely try to hide how much the domain is worth to them, to try to get a bargain. This is an inherently subjective process. Unfortunately it's not a great fit for Webmasters SE Q&A to have people weigh in with their opinions on your "tier" of domain name rarity. I've marked this as duplicate; please check the linked thread for some advice on how to properly price a domain in general. Good luck with your sale!

There are sites providing auctions for domain names - GoDaddy are quite active in this space. But a direct sale like this usually attracts a higher price than one might expect at auction (30% or so). Ultimately though its a question of guesswork/how much someone is willing to pay.
